# How to run Docker commands as non-root user in Docker in Docker?

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker

RUN addgroup docker && \
    adduser -DH demo && \
    addgroup demo docker

CMD /bin/sh
```

In this image, I'm creating a user called demo, which is then added to a group called docker. This is pretty much how full fledged environments are set up so that non-root/non-sudo users can issue docker commands. However, it doesn't work for me. What am I missing? I tried mapping the user and groups (via user, and group id's) to the user on the host system, but it still didn't work. I'm running this in Docker for Mac Beta (1.12.0-rc3-beta18).

Comment: You are missing a lot.    If you want to run apps in a container as a user, you use:

     USER myuser

But it sounds like you expect to have a user within docker, exist in groups on the host, and administer the hosts docker.

If you want a docker container to be able to control the host docker instance... You need to use the docker API.

Comment: @Psycho Punch care to elaborate more on your use case here? The host system will not know about the users within a container. From what I know is that containers are isolated from the host. That is, `container.root != host.root` user. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SamuelToh this is part of an experiment that will hopefully lead to setting up a continuous integration environment running inside a Docker container, but is able to create sibling containers. I'm not really trying to map host users; it was just an exploratory step.

Comment: @user2105103 Like I said previously, I don't intend to map host users to container users. However, you're right about the part where I want the container to be able to manage the host.

Comment: @PsychoPunch I see what u mean. unfortunately I have no experience with nesting containers within another. I tried googling for u alittle using key words like `nested container docker` turns out the first few pages are usually 'this is a bad practise'. See link. https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/ Probably worth a study

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension to the problem's comment.

So OP's use-case is about investigating a continuous integration environment through using the `docker within docker` architecture, or approach if you like.

From docker's official blog posting for [nested containers](https://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/), **yes** this can be done however, as explained further by jpetazzo, a pioneer contributor to the nested container concept; to get the architecture to work properly a significant amount of hackie effort might be needed as the nesting architecture is not perfect mainly due to the following disadvantages;

**Example:**

1 - Security profile

> When starting a container, the “inner Docker” might try to apply
>   security profiles that will conflict or confuse the “outer Docker.”

2 - Storage

> The second issue is linked to storage drivers. When you run Docker in
>   Docker, the outer Docker runs on top of a normal filesystem (EXT4,
>   BTRFS, what have you) but the inner Docker runs on top of a
>   copy-on-write system (AUFS, BTRFS, Device Mapper, etc., depending on
>   what the outer Docker is setup to use). There are many combinations
>   that won’t work.
>   2
>   3 - Difficult to reuse images in child containers
>
> And what about the build cache? That one can get pretty tricky too.
>   People often ask me, “I’m running Docker-in-Docker; how can I use the
>   images located on my host, rather than pulling everything again in my
>   inner Docker?”

**Q)** Possible solution to this problem?

**A:** I guess the reason why OP was experimenting with a nested container architecture was so that he can use a container, as some form of root, then orchestrate its child containers through docker commands?

If that is the idea then this is still achievable through the standard non-nested way. That is, instead of sending docker commands down the stream, you send it back to the host instance and let the host instance do the command for you the root container instead. Example; use docker REST api to send docker commands from a container.